# lightmap equivalent with realtime shadow

Tags: unity, lightmap

[image]

i'm using in Unity free edition.

I try to bake a lightmap which equivalent feeling with Unity's real time light map and shadowing, like left figure.

But the result is the right figure.

How can i set a paremters of lighting window to get result like left figure?

--added--

here's all of screenshots.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the difference between the two images is the use of ambient occlusion

Comment: Add a screenshot of your Lighting setup tab.

Comment: i found a solution. a problem was ambient occlusion.

Comment: The same thing the first comment said? Who would have guessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution. a problem was ambient occlusion